# POST CURL to JSON using PHP (use Cookie.txt)

Tags: php, json, curl, cookies

I want to POST some CURL to a REST API with the use of a PHP Frontend.
A Short Description of my Project ... 
The user (we call him Anton) logs in, on a classic Login Form on the Startsite. After that the user should be logged in until he wants to logout (But thats not the issue here). The main task of the user is to fill a Form with a projectname and a description. After a submit, the data are transferred to a JSON Object which creates the Project in the Software. When I run the CURL commands manually via the terminal, everything works fine. But my PHP Script, unfortunately not.

Login works fine in Terminal

```
curl -v \
     -c cookie.txt \
     -X POST \
     -F j_username=Anton \
     -F j_password=pw \
     http://test.com/login.json
```

Login works fine in PHP

```
<?php
        //Login
        error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
        ini_set('display_errors', '1');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://test.com/login.json");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        $data = array(
            'j_username' => 'Anton',
            'j_password' => 'pw',
        );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        ?>
```

**create Projekt works fine in Terminal but not in php
Create a Projekt ... i have absolutely no idea !
How do i use the Cookie.txt and how do i fill the array (-d part) with the data ?

... and how can I stay logged in to create a projekt?

```
curl -v \
         -b cookie.txt \
         -X POST \
         -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
         -d '{"name":"name12345", "description":"Some Kind of Description"}' \
         http://test.com/productions.json
```

edit... 
but it actually not work. i have problems to use the cookie.txt :(

```
<?php
// //Create Production

function post_to_url($url, $data) {
   $fields = '';
   foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
      $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
   }
   rtrim($fields, '&');

   $post = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   $result = curl_exec($post);

   curl_close($post);
}

$data = array(
   "name" => "Max",
   "description" => "Some kind of description"
);


post_to_url("http://test.com/productions.json", $data);

print_r($data);

?>
```

I strongly believe in your help.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you are missing 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); // this is where you read the cookie from

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I add setopt to my php code but there is no significant change for the function.

Array
(
    [name] => Max
    [description] => Some kind of description
)

thats the Array $data.

Answer (score 0):

it would be very very very kind of you, if someone could translate THIS Curl POST...

```
curl -v \
         -b cookie.txt \
         -X POST \
         -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
         -d '{"name":"name12345", "description":"Some Kind of Description"}' \
         http://test.com/productions.json
```

... to PHP with the use of CURL_SETOPT.

Thank you very much !!!!